# function with getElementById not working

Tags: javascript

```
    function signup() {
    var username = document.getElementById("user").value
    var password = document.getElementById("pass").value
    if (username != false && password != false) {
        alert("Whats up " + username);
    }
   }
```

I made a button with an onclick that sets up to signup() and I made 2 text boxes with the ids "username" and "password". For some reason this code doesn't work. Any help? Also I tried to make it just alert username but it still doesn't work.

Edit: Here are the inputs

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="cool" id="user" placeholder="Username"><br />
<input type="password" class="cool" id="pass" placeholder="Password"><br />
<input type="button" class ="button" value="Sign up" name="signup" onclick="signup()">
</form>
```

Comment: You said textbox ids are `username` and `password` then it should be `document.getElementById("username")` and `document.getElementById("password")`

Comment: Not a syntax error, but why are you comparing string values to boolean `false`? Also you spelt "What's" incorrectly.

Comment: Make sure that you have an `input` tag with the id is **user** and an `input` tag with id is **pass**?

Comment: Can you also post some of the html, please?

Comment: Okay, I updated to show my html inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change the `name` attribute value of the button to avoid the same as the function name.

Code html will look like this:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" class="cool" id="user" placeholder="Username"><br />
   <input type="password" class="cool" id="pass" placeholder="Password"><br />
   <input type="button" class ="button" value="Sign up" name="signup-changed" onclick="signup()">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, I have found the cause of your problem. I have updated the answer, please review and tell me your problem has been resolved?

Comment: Thanks man, that worked! I didn't even know that you couldn't have the same name as function.

Answer (score 0):

You metioned ID of inputs are `username` and `password` then it should be `document.getElementById("username")` and `document.getElementById("password")`

```
  function signup() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value
    if (username != false && password != false) {
        alert("Whats up " + username);
    }
   }
```

Comment: No they're called user and pass.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you equating to false?

The values of your elements are integers, not Boolean. Writing a compareter of == or !=, you have to use type string.

```
username == 'string'
```

Try

```
    if(username.length > 0 && password.length > 0 )
    {
        alert('hi ' + username);
    }
```

Comment: That's *a* problem, but I doubt it is *the* problem considering that `"test" != false` is `true`.

Comment: I guess it means your definition than of the issue he's having. He's stating it doesn't work, and by that im assume he's trying to validate a password to some sort of correlation. So it would seem knowing of the types would be of benefit perhaps. @nnnnnn

Comment: My point is that even with `!= false` the alert *will* be displayed if both the `username` and `password` strings are not empty strings (and not strings with just spaces or zeros).

Comment: Well right, but I mean what use does that do when you're trying to validate a username and password.@nnnnnn

Comment: Again, I'm not saying `!= false` is what the OP should be using, I'm just saying that it isn't a syntax error and it will work for the test they're doing so that on its own doesn't explain the problem they're having. Note their alert is trying to greet the user with the name entered, so presumably OP is testing with a non-blank name. (Also, though testing the string lengths is what they should do, you've reversed the condition in that the OP's code is testing for non-empty strings and yours is testing for empty strings.)

Comment: Ah, ok I understand now. I'm on an iPad so I didn't execute it, but thanks for pointing that out. I'll change the loop. @nnnnnn